# Old Powerbuilder app, trying to run on Windows 7 64bit with SQL2008 Connectivity

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder

So we've an old circa 2000 Powerbuilder App that we've been maintaining all this time.  Its been working great until I tried to get it going on my new Windows 7 64-bit machine.

First, the old SQL 2000 client install we always have used won't install.
Second, after installed SQL 2008 connectivity tools, the app fails to connect to our database.

The error is "DBMS is not supported in your current installation"

Im worried that the 32bit PBMSS90.dll just cannot deal with the 64bit SQL drivers.  I have no idea what to do at this point.

If you can offer any help, its greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I encountered is that the ancient Microsoft SQL Server driver we had been using (MSS) cannot be installed on a 64bit machine.

To make matters worse, the current SQL Native Client driver (SNC) is not at all compatible with the Powerbuilder 9.0 app we had.

The solution was to installed SNC and recompile the application in Powerbuilder 11.5 or later (in our case we used 12).

The application now runs, and connects to the database.  There are a few issues to work out yet, as MSS and SNC regard char type variables differently, but the major hurdle was covered.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Just load the 32-bit connectivity software for SQL Server. The 32-bit and 64-bit should be able to co-exist nicely, and PowerBuilder (and any other 32-bit software that accesses SQL Server) will be able to use 32-bit.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: +1 this is what we did.  It worked with Powerbuilder 11.5 on Windows 7 64bit and also 2008 Server R2.  You can download from here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=228DE03F-3B5A-428A-923F-58A033D316E1 (scroll down to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client, x86 package)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried this already, and I actually used your link too and tried again.  When I try to installed the x86 package it tells me that its not compatible with this operating system.  Only the 64bit driver will install. :(

Comment: I just retried it, and I can't get it to run on my Win7 x64 machine.  Which is v. strange because I can see it already installed, and my PB app can connect.  Maybe my memory is wrong, and it was the x64 version of the sqlncli that I installed.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 comes with a virtual machine IIRC that can emulate all MS operating systems back to Windows 95.  If this is an OS environment problem try loading your app in an XP virtual machine.